# Вывести всего одну запись за весь цикл

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, товарищи знатоки. 
Есть такой код. Отвечает за загрузку файлов. В случае успешной загрузки файла выводится сообщение с ссылкой на этот файл. 
Необходимо вывести всего одну ссылку на сгенерированную галерею.

```
    <?
    //ширина и высота в пикселях
    $pic_weight = 50000;
    $pic_height = 50000;
    $gal_id = date('YmdHis').rand(1000,9999);
    if (isset($_FILES))
    {

      //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
      foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
      {
      echo "<hr>";
        //директория загрузки
        $uploaddir = "up/";
        //новое имя изображения
        $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.png';
        //путь к новому изображению
        $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

        //Проверка расширений загружаемых изображений
        if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" ||
        $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
        {
          //черный список типов файлов
          $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
          foreach ($blacklist as $item)
          {
            if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
            {
              echo "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
              exit;
            }
          }

          //перемещаем файл из временного хранилища
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
          {
            //получаем размеры файла
            $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
            //проверяем размеры файла, если они нам подходят, то оставляем файл
            if ($size[0] < $pic_weight && $size[1] < $pic_height)
            {
                $newfile = basename($uploadfile, ".png");
                $fn=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    //              echo 'Файл <a href="im/' . $newfile . '">' . $_FILES['file']['name'][$k] . '</a> загружен.['.$gal_id.' ]<br>';

    // запись данных в mysql

//ссылка на галерею
    //echo '<a href="list.php?gal='.$gal_id.'">ok</a> загружен.['.$gal_id.' ]<br>';
            }
            //если размеры файла нам не подходят, то удаляем файл unlink($uploadfile);
            else
            {
              echo "<center><br>Размер пикселей превышает допустимые нормы.</center>";
              unlink($uploadfile);
            }
          }
          else
            echo "<center><br>Файл не загружен, вернитесь и попробуйте еще раз.</center>";
        }
        else
          echo "<br>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Zayac, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И в чем проблема? Там где надо выводить прописываете

```
if ($Flag) {echo "Вывод"; $flag=False;}
```

Сперва вверху скрипта написать `$flag=true;`

Comment: Думал в этом направлении, но видимо мало думал. Спасибо, то что доктор прописал)